# Button does not close on click

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

When I click on navbar it does show the menu (as in on my phone) but when I click again on (small 3 lines  (-) like this is sort of what button look like that I click on when the screen is small as it menu collapse) it does not work when I have to close the menu on clicking again. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
   
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="navbarStyle.css" />

</head>


<body>
    <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['login_success'])) {
    echo ' <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark p-4 sticky-top">';
    echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
    echo ' <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brandname</a>';
    echo ' <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" >';
    echo ' <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>';

    echo ' </button>';

    echo ' <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">';
    echo ' <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">';
    echo ' <li class="nav-item active">';
    echo ' <a href="signuphome.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="nav-link">Home</a>';

    echo ' </li>';

    echo ' <li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="data.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"  class="nav-link">Data</a>';
    echo ' </li>';

    echo ' <li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="moredata.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"  class="nav-link">Datamore</a>';
    echo ' </li>';

    echo '<li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="profile.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"  class="nav-link">Profile</a>';
    echo '</li>';

    echo ' <li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="about.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"  class="nav-link">About</a>';
    echo '</li>';

    echo '<li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="contacts.php" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"  class="nav-link">Contact us</a>';
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';

    echo '
    <form action="logoutbackend.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="logout-submit" class="logout_button" style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:12px;  background-color: rgb(33, 128, 46);
    ">Logout</button>
    </form>';

    echo '</div>';

    echo ' </div>';
    echo ' </nav>';

} else {
    echo ' <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark p-4 sticky-top">';
    echo '<div class="container-fluid">';
   
    echo ' <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">ShowCo</a>';
    echo ' <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" >';
    echo ' <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>';

    echo ' </button>';

    echo ' <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">';
    echo ' <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">';
    echo ' <li class="nav-item active">';
    echo ' <a href="index.php" class="nav-link">Home</a>';

    echo ' </li>';

    echo ' <li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="data.php" class="nav-link">Data</a>';
    echo ' </li>';

    echo ' <li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="about.php" class="nav-link">About</a>';
    echo '</li>';

    echo '<li class="nav-item">';
    echo ' <a href="contacts.php" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>';
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';

    echo '</div>';

    echo ' </div>';
    echo ' </nav>';

}
?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        let pageName = location.pathname.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
        let currentLink = $('.navbar-nav .nav-item a[href="' + pageName + '"]');
        if (currentLink) {

          $('.navbar-nav .nav-item').removeClass('active');
          currentLink.parent().addClass('active');
        }
      });
    
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you mean is that, when you click out of the menu, menu does not collapse ? It is hard to understand your problem here

Comment: @MaxiGui I meant when on menu (as in the button) it shows all the menu content such as home, about etc. But, when I click again on the same button the menu should get collapse or close rather staying there. I will post a image here in a moment. Sorry if it was confusing before.

Comment: @MaxiGui I have added the image and marked with red mark, that's the button when I tap on second time it does collapse the menu rather the menu stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've included jquery file two times. That may cause issue.